# Very slow text entry using Selenium IEDriverServer?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

Running Selenium IEDriverServer 3.5.1 32bit, I am experiencing very, very slow text entry in Internet Explorer v11.  Oddly, if I switch to IEDriverServer 3.4.0 (also 32bit) it is not slow, but overall test execution slows down somewhat (this issue only surfaced a few days ago, oddly.  Previously I was using 3.5.1 with no issues).  Has anyone found a legitimate solution to this issue?  Here is my webdriver definition:

```
DesiredCapabilitiescaps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer(); 
caps.setBrowserName("internet explorer"); 
caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_PERSISTENT_HOVERING, false); 
caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true); 
caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.NATIVE_EVENTS, false); 
caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS, true); 
caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true); 
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

Additionally, on IE itself, I have the following set:

- All the security zones set to protected mode ON
- Advanced > Security> Enable 64-bit processes for Enhanced Protected Mode is unchecked.
- Connnections > Lan Settings > Automatically Detect Settings is unchecked

Every time I googled this issue, I find an answer from a year ago, usually related to Selenium 2.53 or something like that.  Has anybody experienced this recently, and if so, how was it fixed?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you work with a mixed-mode of 64-bit and 32-bit processes in IE the problem of slow typing occurs. 
Assuming that you use the 64 bits version of the driver:
The solution would be to use the 32 bit version of IEDriverServer 3.5.1.

Comment: No, I use the 32 bit version.  I meant to add that to the question, don't know how I missed it.

Comment: And what kind of Internet Explorer is installed on your system?

Comment: I am running ie11

Comment: The 32 or 64 bits version?

Comment: The OS is 64 bit, but from what I understand IE almost always uses the 32bit version of the application.  I can't tell specifically which version is launched, but both versions are installed.

Answer (score 1):

The performance of sendKeys is not good with IE, so in my case, I create following work-around to set text to elements:

```
@Override
public boolean setValue(String text) {
    logger.info(String.format("<%s(%s) set value '%s'", el.getTagName(), el.getText(), text));
    try {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webElementFinder.getDriver();
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].value = arguments[1];",
                waitForElementVisible(config.getBrowserElementFinderTimeout()), text);
        return true;
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        logger.warn(e.getMessage());
        logger.warn(
                String.format("<%s(%s) Element not visible within timeout period", el.getTagName(), el.getText()));
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 32 bit IEdriver.

Please go through this link for more information:

**https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5116**

Comment: I am using the 32 bit IEDriver